# Performance issue when finding/assigning the similarity value between sentences within two dataframes

Tags: performance, spacy, word2vec, similarity, lda

I am trying to calculate the similarity value between lists of strings using spacy word2vec, but the code is talking so much time, and google colab stops working at the end.
The code I come-up with is mentioned below; mainly I have two dataframes, the first includes a list of comments (more than 1.5 million) while the second includes a set of LDA topics represented as topic name and keywords (39 topics).  What is required is to create a new column (within the first dataframe) holding the similarity value between the comments and each of the topics' keywords (i.e. 39 columns to be added to the first dataframe, each one represents the similarity values between the comments and one topic).
I run the code for small data set and it worked fine. However for the 1.5M comments and 39 topics keywords, it for more than 2.5 hours then stops. I am not sure if this is the optimal code to achieve the task, any advise is appreciated.

The code is:

```
for index, row in Post_sent_df.iterrows():  #first dataframe
row = Post_sent_df['Sent_text'][index]
doc1 = nlp2(row)
if doc1.vector_norm:
   for index_tp, row_tp in topics_words_df.iterrows(): #second dataframe
       row_tp = topics_words_df['TopicKeyWords'][index_tp]
       doc2 = nlp2(row_tp)
       if doc2.vector_norm:
          sim_value = (doc1.similarity(doc2))
          col_name = str(index_tp)
          Post_sent_df.at[index , index_tp] = sim_value
```

Comment: When it "stops", has the process crashed with any message?

Comment: no message, just the runtime disconnected

Comment: Is this happening in something like a Jupyter Notebook? If so, is the runtime local or remote? It's possible that the runtime system has run out-of-memory; if you are able to look in its logs, there may be an indication of that. I suppose it might also be possible the code is hitting some timeout - is that a possibility where you're running it?

Comment: It happened in google colab (hosted runtime). I am running it now on Jupyter notebook using my local runtime on my laptop (windows, core i5) and it's running since more than 16 hrs (and still running), is that normal? In google colab for around (2000) comments, the code took almost 2hrs, so for 1.5 comments I expect much more time.

Comment: Well, from a quick glance at your simple loops, it seems runtime should grow roughly linearly with more texts to process. So if 2000 texts take 2h, then 1.5M texts – 750x more – should take about 2h * 750, or 1500 hours, or 62.5 days. How long are the comments, in words? What's the real ultimate goal? (Why are you filling 39 columns with this peculiar measure of word2vec-similarity-with-an-LDA-topic-words?) I'd guess most of the time is spent in the SpaCy `nlp2()` call - are you sure you need everything it's doing?

Comment: Thank You for your response. The idea is to calculate “aspect based sentiment analysis”. I first divided comments per sentences (that's why 1.5M sentences), then assuming that each sentence represents one topic, I tried to find the most similar topic through the similarity function. Each of the rows in the second dataframe represents the top 20 keywords for one topic, so each of the 39 added column will represent the similarity between the sentence and the topic.  I am trying the code for one topic only, but it is still running since around 3 hrs now (it seems it will need 1.6days!)

Comment: I see. But note: typically once you've trained a LDA model, you can use that model to directly analyze the topics in new texts, using the same logic as deduced the topics in the 1st place. Your word2vec-comparison-to-LDA-topic-words is a hybrid approach I've not seen before. It might work! But I somewhat doubt it'd outperform the LDA-native topic-analysis. And I believe the usual native LDA approach would require zero calls to the expensive `nlp2()` function. (IIUC you're using that just to get word-vectors, but most of its runtime is probably doing other things, & you may not need it at all!)

Answer (score 0):

As gojomo mentioned in his comments, most of the time is used to run the nlp2() function without a real need for its processing, and as I just want to calculate the similarity between word2vectors, I decided to use nlp() through an apply function to calculate the word2vec for the comments, and do the same for the topics, and then loop through the generated word2vecs to calculate the cosine similarity manually, below is the code I used:

```
#Define function to get word2vec for a sentence 
 def get_vec(x):
     doc = nlp2(x)
     vec = doc.vector
     return vec 

#calculate vec for keywords 
topics_words_df['key_words_vec'] = topics_words_df['TopicKeyWords'].apply(lambda x: get_vec(x))

#calculate vec for comments 
Post_sent_df['Sent_vec'] = Post_sent_df['Sent_text'].apply(lambda x: get_vec(x))

# calculate cosine similarity 
for index, row in Post_sent_df.iterrows():
    row = Post_sent_df['Sent_vec'][index]
    for index_tp, row_tp in topics_words_df.iterrows():
        row_tp = topics_words_df['key_words_vec'][index_tp]
        cosine_similarity = np.dot(row, row_tp)/(np.linalg.norm(row)* np.linalg.norm(row_tp))
        col_name = str(index_tp)
        Post_sent_df.at[index , index_tp] = cosine_similarity
```